# Single web socket connection for multiple routes

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket

I have a react application where I stream data through html web socket. I have two components in two different routes using the same socket connection. I want to use the same web socket connection for both the components. I have 2 questions:

1. Where shall I create the web socket so that I can use the same connection for both the components?
2. Is there any way to create the socket only once and use the same socket for multiple routes without closing and re-opening it?